# Bindings - empty event name/Change Visibility

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm building a *Xamarin.Android* bindings of an Jar, but i'm encountering this problem: `empty event name in IMpoxListener.AddListener`.

Then when i try to use the method *AddListener* of my generated class this error is raised: `The method or operation is not implemented`.

From what i have analized, if i can change the visibility of a field, maybe i can bypass this problem.

Anyone knows if i can solve one of this problems ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change visibilitiy of a class or method:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='namespace']/class[@name='ClassName']" name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='namespace']/class[@name='ClassName']/method[@name='MethodName']" name="visibility">public</attr>
```

To get correct path info, go to Binding project's obj/Debug/generated/src/TargetFileName.cs